# Converting const unsigned int to unsigned int in template parameter

Tags: c++

With the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template< class T, unsigned int NVectorDimension = 3 >
class Vector
{
};

template< unsigned int TDimension >
int RunTest( void )
{
  const unsigned int VectorDimension = 4;
  typedef Vector< int, VectorDimension >     VectorPixelType;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  return 0;
}
```

I get:

```
In function ‘int RunTest()’:
12:40: error: could not convert template argument ‘VectorDimension’ to ‘unsigned int’
error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
```

Any ideas what is wrong with that?

David

Comment: What compiler is that? gcc can handle it (other than RunTest not returning a value).

Comment: GCC 4.6. It worked fine in GCC 4.4. I've been told it also doesn't work in GCC 4.7. Is there something small I can do to change it to make it work with these newer gcc's?

Comment: Aside from `RunTest` missing a return statement, I don't see anything wrong with this code... :-/  This looks like a compiler bug (I did a quick search of the GCC Bugzilla database but didn't find anything; someone else might have better luck).  Does `typedef Vector< int, 4 > VectorPixelType;` work?

Comment: const_cast, insofar as you just need to get this to work?

Comment: Matt - what would I const_cast ? And are you saying that is a bad idea?

Comment: I tried this:
typedef Vector< int, const_cast<unsigned int>(VectorDimension) >     VectorPixelType;
but it complained that unsigned int is not a pointer or reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was indeed a bug in gcc. It has been fixed now:
http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48657

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, that should work fine. Otherwise, is it affordable for you to change your `class Vector` declaration a bit ? It can be given a try.

```
template< class T, const unsigned int NVectorDimension = 3 >
class Vector  //   ^^^^^  adding const here
{
};
```

If that doesn't work, then a macro work around can be tried as a last resort.

```
int RunTest( void )
{
#define VectorDimension 4
  typedef Vector< int, VectorDimension >     VectorPixelType;
   // ...
#undef VectorDimension
}
```

Comment: Hm, that doesn't seem to change anything:
#include <iostream>

template< class T, const unsigned int NVectorDimension = 3 >
class Vector
{
};

template< unsigned int TDimension >
void RunTest( void )
{
  const unsigned int VectorDimension = 4;
  typedef Vector< int, VectorDimension >     VectorPixelType;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  return 0;
}

Comment: Since, `VectorDimension` is a local to RunTest, can you `#define` it as shown in edited code (not a good idea though) ?